Using the rust tracing library with daemonize
I would like to use the tracing library together with deamonize.
Consider the following example
use tracing::info;
use tracing_subscriber::layer::SubscriberExt;
use tracing_subscriber::{fmt, Registry};

fn main() {
    let file_appender = tracing_appender::rolling::never("/tmp", "test.log");
    let (non_blocking, _guard) = tracing_appender::non_blocking(file_appender);

    let subscriber = Registry::default().with(fmt::Layer::default().with_writer(non_blocking));
    tracing::subscriber::set_global_default(subscriber).unwrap();
    
    info!("Foo");
    daemonize::Daemonize::new().start().unwrap();
    info!("Bar");
}

The "Foo" log message gets written into the log-file while the "Bar" message after the Daemonize does not. How would this be possible? It works with the log library. Ultimatly, I would like to use tracing_log so can use existing (async) code that uses log together with libraries that use tracing.

From https://github.com/knsd/daemonize/blob/master/daemonize/src/lib.rs#L339 I understand that parent will be killed meaning info!("Bar"); will never be reached. And about "It works with the log library." probably log library using seperate thread so it wont be killed and it will still work.

The program will continue to run after the daemonize. Of course, stdin/out streams from the parent will not be available anymore. But writing to other files is ok.
